# processing data from local postgres in play framework 1.2.5

Tags: java, database, postgresql, playframework, playframework-1.x

I was working on a simple login application using play framwork 1.2.5 and connection to local postgres database was established; the problem is attempting to read from database inorder to verify if login info and user match.

the issue is i get a blank page on the url:.../application/signin  while an html page rendered from signIn method should output this: TODO write content

ps:i have uploaded jdbc driver is lib

thanks

```
    App/conf
    # If you need a full JDBC configuration use the following :
   db.url=jdbc:postgresql:postgres
   db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
   db.user=postgres
   db.pass=******
   #
  ---------------------------------------------
     the login page
     <body>
        #{form @Application.signIn()}
        <form>
            Online ID <input type="text" name ="onlineID" value="${onlineID}"><br>
            Passcode  <input type="text" name ="passcode" value="${passcode}">
            <input type ="submit" value="Sign in">
        </form>
       #{/form}

      </body>
    ---------------------------------------------
   controller.App.java
   public static void signIn(String onlineID, String passcode) {

         login existing = new login(onlineID,passcode);
         boolean verify=existing.check(existing.getOnlineID(),existing.getPassCode());
         if(verify)
           render("@Application.account");

    }


    ---------------------------------------------
    model.login.java

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import play.data.validation.*;
    import play.db.DB;

    public class login {
    @Required public String onlineID;
    @Required public String passcode;

    public login(){}
    public login(String onlineID,String passcode){
    this.onlineID=onlineID;
    this.passcode=passcode;
    }

    public void setOnlineID(String onlineID){
    this.onlineID=onlineID;
    }
    public String getOnlineID(){
    return this.onlineID;
    }

    public void setPassCode(String passcode){
    this.passcode=passcode;
    }
    public String getPassCode(){
    return this.passcode;
    }

    public boolean check(String onlineID,String passcode){

            boolean verify=false;
            Connection conn=null;
            Statement stmt=null;
            try{

                conn = DB.getConnection();
                stmt=conn.createStatement();
                String sql;
                sql="SELECT Cust_ID,password from corebanking.customer";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                while(rs.next()){
                     int uID=rs.getInt("Cust_ID");
                     String ssn=rs.getString("SSN");
                     String pas=rs.getString("password");
                     String loginID=Integer.toString(uID);

                     if (onlineID.equals(loginID) && passcode.equals(pas)){
                         verify=true; 
                     }

                }

                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
          //finally block used to close resources
          try{
             if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
          }catch(SQLException se2){
          }// nothing we can do
          try{
             if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
          }catch(SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
          }//end finally try
       }//end try
       return verify;
       }


      }

      ---------------------------------------------
      routes
      GET     /                                       Application.index

      GET    /                                       controllers.Application.signIn()
```

Comment: why don't you use jpa?

Comment: thanks. wanted to test local postgres then connect to cloud postgres on heroku

Comment: update: this app worked processing data when i used mysql instead of postgres

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you access the page:.../application/signin in order to display the log-in form. Since the log-in page is not static resource, Play Framework must pass through a controller to get to this page.

However, your Application controller in the signin method doesn't get any parameters in the first request, and the verify variable is false, and thus returning blank page.

You should create another method in the Application controller like this:

```
public static void showLogin() {
    render("/path/to/login.html");
}
```

And your first request should be sent to the .../application/showLogin. Then you'll get the login page, and after submitting the right username and password, you should see your 'account' page.

However, will still get a blank screen when you'll miss the username or password. You should add the following in your sign-in method

```
public static void signIn(String onlineID, String passcode) {

     login existing = new login(onlineID,passcode);
     boolean verify=existing.check(existing.getOnlineID(),existing.getPassCode());
     if(verify)
       render("@Application.account");
     // the following code is added
     else 
       render("@Application.authenticationFailed")

}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you Ristes! I have will update soon what's up with my prostgres connection!